# How to change the route url of openshift oauth authentication?

Tags: routes, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise, okd

Openshift Version: 4.7

I'm trying to update the route url of the openshift webconsole and openshift OAuth athentication.
I could successfully do it for openshift console by using

```
oc edit route.route.openshift.io/console -n openshift-console
```

Changed `console-openshift-console.apps.lab.okd.local` to `console-openshift-console.apps.lab.okd.local.<service-node-ip>.nip.io`

This worked.
Here my intension to add nip.io is to eliminate the manual host entries.

Now I need to change the route url of the openshift oauth as well because login to openshift webconsole redirects the page to openshift OAuth.
I tried to update the route url using:

```
oc edit route.route.openshift.io/oauth-openshift -n openshift-authentication
```

But once I update the route url from `oauth-openshift.apps.lab.okd.local` to `oauth-openshift.apps.lab.okd.local.<service-node-ip>.nip.io` and save, the changes gets reverted to original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly edit this`route`as it is managed by an operator and as soon as the operator detects a change in the objects it manages, it reset them. This is the standard operator way of working
As for changing the OAuth URL, you can do it with OCP v4.9 as described here: [Customizing the internal OAuth server URL](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/authentication/configuring-internal-oauth.html#customizing-the-oauth-server-url_configuring-internal-oauth)
It is announced in v4.9 release notes here: [Customizing the OAuth server URL](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/release_notes/ocp-4-9-release-notes.html#ocp-4-9-security-customize-oauth-server-url)
I don't think it is possible to do it before OCP v4.9